# The following required properties are missing: fb:app_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments, facebook-debugger

I check and confirm meta tags in my website

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxx" />
```

But [Facebook Developers Debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)

still giving error

```
Missing Properties The following required properties are missing: fb:app_id
```

How can I fix this error?

Url is [link](https://uae.yallamotor.com/car-news/jeep-adventure-days-2018-in-the-uae-4945)

Comment: The only possible answer is that you haven't included it. But it is impossible to say what you did wrong because we don't know what URL you are trying to share

Comment: @WizKid url is : https://uae.yallamotor.com/car-news/jeep-adventure-days-2018-in-the-uae-4945

Comment: I update question also

Answer (score 0):

Use [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=YOUR_URL) tool and use the `Scrape Again` button to flush Facebook's cache.